# A sorting problem with the DataGridView in WinForms when the dgv is DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms

My `DataGridView sorting method` does not work and would not be used wiht the `compiler`.

#### Where i use dgv:

```
public void LoadData(IList conTable)
    {
        var mtc = new Conversions();
        dgvDetailedTable.DataSource = null; 
        dgvDetailedTable.DataSource = mtc.ToSortableBindingList(conTable);
        dgvDetailedTable.RowTemplate.Height = UiConsts.RowHeight;
    }
```

#### The Sorting event:

```
private void DgvDetailedTable_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var itemsToSelect = new MisTable[_selectedDetailedItems.Length];
        _selectedDetailedItems.CopyTo(itemsToSelect, 0);
        DgvOperations.MarkSelectedItems(dgvDetailedTable, itemsToSelect);
    }
```

Comment: is your second snippet correct? i'm afraid you are trying to filter when you want to sort

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: ok., referring [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples), the ```DgvDetailedTable_Sorted``` will be fired after the sorting happened. Since your are assigning the datasource at ```dgvDetailedTable.DataSource = mtc.ToSortableBindingList(conTable);```, your sorting has to occur in the toSortableBindingList. Alternatively refer to [SortOrder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) and SortedColumn of DGV properties on MSDN

Comment: Follow the example  of ```SortOrder``` (linked in my previous comment), and figure out how to implement the ```dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);``` matching your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help, but I'm not sure you should use Sorted event for it.
You can use this code below at the end of binding and when you add a new item it will sort properly again.

```
public void LoadData(IList conTable)
    {
        var mtc = new MisTableConversions();
        dgvDetailedTable.DataSource = null; 
        dgvDetailedTable.DataSource = mtc.ToSortableBindingList(conTable);
        dgvDetailedTable.RowTemplate.Height = UiConsts.RowHeight;
        // Use sorting here
        this.DgvDetailedTable.Sort(this.DgvDetailedTable.Columns["Name"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```